# bc arithmetic error

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, lemonbar

I am following this guide to try and setup a lemonbar config: http://blog.z3bra.org/2014/04/meeting-at-the-bar.html

Now almost everything works flawlessly except for this line:

```
bc <<< "scale=2; 100 - $f / $t * 100" | cut -d. -f1
```

In this function:

```
memused() {
    read t f <<< `grep -E 'Mem(Total|Free)' /proc/meminfo |awk '{print $2}'`
    bc <<< "scale=2; 100 - $f / $t * 100" | cut -d. -f1
}
```

I get the following error `(standard_in) 1: syntax error`

Now from what I can tell I should be adding double brackets around the equation `(())` but I have tried a ton of different arrangements and nothing fixes the error.

Answer (score 3):

`awk` can do all of `read`'s, `cut`'s, `grep`'s and `bc`'s jobs here:

```
 awk -F': *' '
   $1 == "MemTotal" {t = $2}
   $1 == "MemFree" {f = $2}
   END {printf "%.1f%%\n", (t - f) * 100 / t}' /proc/meminfo
```

Beware that not all `awk` implementations will output 40,5% instead of 40.5 in locales where comma is used as the decimal radix (GNU `awk` only does it in POSIX mode like when `$POSIXLY_CORRECT` is in the environment). Use `LC_ALL=C awk...` to force the decimal radix to period/dot.

Change `%.1f` to `%.0f` if you don't want a decimal part at all. That will round to the *nearest* integer. Use `%d` instead if you want to truncate the decimal part (get 99% instead of 100% for 99.999).

Your `` read t f <<< `grep -E 'Mem(Total|Free)' /proc/meminfo |awk '{print $2}'` `` would have worked in older versions of `bash` assuming an unmodified `$IFS`.

In `` cmd <<< `code` ``, `bash` used to split the output of `code` on characters of `$IFS` (which by default includes newline) and join them with the first character of `$IFS` (by default space) before feeding as stdin to the command. So in your case, those two lines of `awk`'s output would end-up being fed as two words on one line as expected by `read t f`. That surprising behaviour (and also differing from the original implementation in `zsh`) was fixed in bash-4.4.

In `bash-4.4` and above, you'd need `{ read t; read f; } <<< "$(awk...)"` (here adding quotes around `$(...)` so it also works in bash-4.3 and before, still assuming the default value of `$IFS`).

Answer (score 1):

## Abstract:

Portable, In one line and using printf:

```
awk '/MemTotal/{t=$2}; /MemFree/{f=$2}; END{printf("%d\n",(1-f/t)*100)}'
```

Only Shell (bash):

```
memused() { : # Print the (integer) value of % of free memory
            local ret ref a t f 
            ret='MemTotal:[ \t]*([0-9]+)';              # Regex for Total memory.
            ref='MemFree:[ \t]*([0-9]+)';               # Regex for Free  memory.
            a=$(</proc/meminfo)                         # Get meminfo in var (a).
            [[ $a =~ $ret ]] && t="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"  # Get Total memory.
            [[ $a =~ $ref ]] && f="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"  # Get Free  memory.
            printf '%s\n' "$(( 100 - 100*f/t )) %"      # Print integer % value.
          }
```

---

## Description

The reason for the complaint of bc is that it is only getting one var.

To reproduce:

```
$ t=150 ; f='' ; bc <<< "scale=2; 100 - $f / $t * 100"
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

One way to avoid that error is to set a default value:

```
$ t=150; f=''; bc <<< "scale=2; 100 - ${f:-0} / ${t:-0} * 100"
100
```

The reason for only one value is that the read is getting the values in separate lines (in bash 4.4). A solution that works well for all bash versions is to use `-d ''`:

```
$ read -d '' t f <<< "`grep -E 'Mem(Total|Free)' /proc/meminfo |awk '{print $2}'`"
$ echo "total=<$t>     free=<$f>"
total=<1922764>     free=<424360>
```

And that also works whether the command expansion is quoted (as it should be)  `` "`grep … '`" `` or not.

But there is no reason to call `grep`, `awk`, `bc` and finally `cut`. One call to awk could do it all:

```
</proc/meminfo awk '/MemTotal/{t=$2}
                    /MemFree/ {f=$2}
                    END{
                        print( (1-f/t)*100 )
                    }
                   '
```

In one line and using printf:

```
awk '/MemTotal/{t=$2};/MemFree/{f=$2};END{printf("%d\n",(1-f/t)*100)}' </proc/meminfo
```

If you want something that works faster and only use the shell (albeit bash):

```
memused() {  : # Print the (integer) value of % of free memory
             local ret ref a t f 
             ret='MemTotal:[ \t]*([0-9]+)';              # Regex for Total memory.
             ref='MemFree:[ \t]*([0-9]+)';               # Regex for Free  memory.
             a=$(</proc/meminfo)                         # Get meminfo in var (a).
             [[ $a =~ $ret ]] && t="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"  # Get Total memory.
             [[ $a =~ $ref ]] && f="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"  # Get Free  memory.
             printf '%s\n' "$(( 100 - 100*f/t )) %"      # Print integer % value.
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The string read by `read` command only contain 1 field, where 2 is expected to fill both `t` and `f` variable.

You can solve it by adding `| tr '\n' ' '` after the `awk` command.

But it would be better to simplify it to just:

```
read t f <<< $(awk '/MemTotal/{t=$2}/MemFree/{f=$2}END{print t,f}' /proc/meminfo)
```